# The shaded solution region in the following graph represents the inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

The shaded solution region in the following graph represents the inequality 
[image]

please help I don't know how determine that from the graph

Comment: firstly, find the straight line eqution

Comment: I think is $$ y=-x-2$$

Comment: The intercept form of a line may help: $\frac{x}5+\frac{y}{-2}=1$ Now check if the origin is on which side!

Answer (score 1):

the general equation of line is
$$y=mx+b$$
from the graph we find the slope is $\frac{2}{5}$ 
so
$$y=\frac{2}{5}x-2$$

the inequality will be
$$y<\frac{2}{5}x-2$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a point on both axes: $A=(5,0)$  and $B=(0,-2)$. A well-known formula says the equation of the  straight line is:
$$\frac x5-\frac y2=1$$
As the left-hand side is $0<1$ at $(0,0)$, not in the shaded region, the latter is defined by the inequation:
$$\frac x5-\frac y2>1\enspace\text{or}\enspace 2x-5y>10.$$